# Can anyone suggest me necessary changes for my code?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning how to concat in pandas.

I am stuck. Getting syntax error like

[image: Code Image]

Not able to figure out what to do. Please Help

Comment: Please add the code as text instead of image.

Comment: And full error output.

Comment: the name of the team are strings....they should be in quotes.. "Delhi daredevil","",""] same for cities\

Comment: put list elements (delhi daredevils etc.) inside quotes. like `{'Teams': ["Delhi Daredevils", ...`

Answer (score -1):

String literals are written inside quotes(Single or double).

```
{"key":"value", "key", "value"}
```

OR

```
{"key": ["value1", "value2"], "key":["value1", "value2"]};
```